# Issues with a setter in a class, assigns None value to attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm learning about classes and inheritance and trying to create a simple abstract class called human and a subclass child, which has to inherit from the parent class. The parent and subclass both have only two attributes - name and age.

I've added a couple of setter methods to verify if the age and the name provided meet certain criteria e.g. if the length of the name is less than 2 characters, whether the age is positive or less than 15 for the subclass. The checks in the setter methods work properly, however, when I provide valid data both attributes in the sub-class assume None value.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Hooman(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = self.set_age(age)
        self.name = self.set_name(name)

    @abstractmethod
    def set_age(self, age):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def set_name(self, name):
        pass


class LilHooman(Hooman):
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        super().__init__(age, name)

    def set_age(self, age):
        if age < 0:
            raise Exception("Age must be positive!")
        elif age > 14:
            raise Exception("Child's age must be less than 15!")
        else:
            self.age = age

    def set_name(self, name):
        if len(name) < 3:
            raise Exception("Name's length should not be less than 3 symbols!")
        else:
            self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: %s, Age: %d" % (self.name, self.age)


a = input()
b = int(input())

A1 = LilHooman(b, a)
print(A1.age, A1.name)
```

With the following input:

```
Mike
14
```

Output:

```
"None None"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your methods `set_age` and `set_name` do not return anything.  So this code is not going to work:

```
def __init__(self, age, name):
    self.age = self.set_age(age)
    self.name = self.set_name(name)
```

Instead you should use:

```
def __init__(self, age, name):
    self.set_age(age)
    self.set_name(name)
```

Comment: Much appreciated!